# Change & Link of Add To Cart Button if product already in cart

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to change the link & text of the Add to Cart button on the archive page if the products is already in cart.

I only allow quantity one per product to be added.
But the default way of Woocommerce is to direct to the single page with the notice.

Instead I would like the user to either

- See the text "View Cart" and direct the user to the cart

or

- See the text "Added" and have no link whatsoever.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To change the text, you need the codes below.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'wc_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'wc_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );

function wc_product_add_to_cart_text( $text, $product ){

    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() );
    $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

    if ( $in_cart ) {
        $text = "View Cart";
    }
    return $text;
}
```

To redirect to cart, this will do it.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wc_add_to_cart_action', 19 );
function wc_add_to_cart_action(){
    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || ! is_numeric( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $product_id             = absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
    $adding_to_cart         = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $product_cart_id        = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
    $in_cart                = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
    if ( $in_cart && $adding_to_cart->is_sold_individually() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_cart_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

or use this for the second part.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'wc_simple_add_to_cart' );
function wc_simple_add_to_cart(){
    global $product;
    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() );
    $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

    if ( $in_cart ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
        echo sprintf( '<form class="cart"><a href="%s" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">%s</a></form>', wc_get_cart_url(), __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
```

---

update

for shop page you need this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', 'wc_product_add_to_cart_url', 10, 2 );
function wc_product_add_to_cart_url( $url, $product ){
    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->get_id() );
    $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

    if ( $in_cart && is_shop() ) {
        $url = wc_get_cart_url();
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, the first part work, to change the text. But when I click on View Cart it still redirects to the product single view page. I did clear my cache.

Comment: try removing this part to check, `&& $adding_to_cart->is_sold_individually()`. Only put `if ( $in_cart )`, let see if that works

Comment: Hi, thank you. Unfortunately it still doesn't work :) I moved my local site to a live dev site [link]http://mbse.thissideupmedia.com/product-category/class-of-business/ [/link]

Comment: the previous code were meant for the product page. I've added a code for the shop page.

Comment: Thank you @Reigel but unfortunately it still doesn't work. But thank you for your efforts. Much appreciated. An alternative approach that work is to use a wildcard redirect, but this will only be a temp fix.

Comment: not really sure why it's not working... I have checked the code before pasting it here... hmm... weird.

Comment: Maybe because this is a archive page for a shop category and not the main page?  Just to make sure we're on the same page :) (1) go to this page http://mbse.thissideupmedia.com/product-category/class-of-business/ (2) Add any product (3) go back to the shop category page bu clicking on "Continue Shopping" (4) Click on "View Cart" of Same Product. The idea is that the user go to the Cart and not the Single Product Page.

Comment: I changed if `( $in_cart && is_shop() ) {` to `if ( $in_cart ) {` but stil no luck.

Comment: I see, I think you have an older version of WooCommerce, what is your WooCommerce version?

Comment: Nope, everything is up to to date. ( I just update the theme storefront from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2 ) Not sure if that is ok to do here on SStackoverflow, and if you will be willing, but i am happy to supply admin access via direct message; it is still a dev site.

Comment: if you'll remove the `if` entirely, would that work? just to see if the link changes..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172481/discussion-between-user1664798-and-reigel).